# NAs in Logical Statements

Tags: r, logical-operators, na

With the statements

```
NAP_Schools_2012_2017$Num_Read_Yrs35_GE80_2015_2017  <- 
  (NAP_Schools_2012_2017$Num_Read_Yrs35_GE80_2017==TRUE) &
  (NAP_Schools_2012_2017$Num_Read_Yrs35_GE80_2016==TRUE) &
  (NAP_Schools_2012_2017$Num_Read_Yrs35_GE80_2015==TRUE)
```

I thought the the final variable would be NA if any of the original variables are NA.

But not quite.

For observations with NA on one of the original variables and TRUE on one of the other variables (e,g. NA T T, or T NA NA) the new variable is appropriately coded as NA.

But for observations with NA on one of the variables and FALSE on one of the other variables (e,g. NA F F) the new variable is inappropriately coded as FALSE. I thought it would be coded as NA. How can I ensure that if any of the original variables are NA the new variable should be NA. I have tried many approaches but none seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From `help('&')`: *NA is a valid logical object. Where a component of x or y is NA, the result will be NA if the outcome is ambiguous. In other words NA & TRUE evaluates to NA, but NA & FALSE evaluates to FALSE. See the examples below.*

Answer (score 0):

If any condition is `FALSE`, combining it with other logical statements won't ever make it evaluate to `TRUE`. There was a `FALSE` already anyway. Therefore, in that case, it is evaluated to `FALSE` and not to `NA`.

So `NA & TRUE` evaluates to `NA`, since it could still go both ways.
And `NA & FALSE` evaluates to `FALSE`, since that is the only possibility since there is 1 `FALSE` already.